# How to upload image in any background image using PHP without Flash?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

[image]

First I will select area using mouse (the area shown with a yellow background) and there I want to upload image using Uplodify or ajax function.

How to select that area using PHP?

Comment: "I want to upload images in main background image of PHP page without using flash" ???? explain

Comment: Go to http://www.w3schools.com/ you can find out everything you need to know about html and css. Your question makes little sense my friend.

Comment: I didn't know that PHP has main background image oO . xD

Comment: @JulienEtienne i wouldnt recommend w3schools - there info is sometimes inaccurate and out of date .... [Mozilla is a much better place to learn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)

Comment: @ManseUK Lets not go there ;), W3Schools is great for touching the surface. Mozilla is not as entertaining for beginners.

Comment: how does this guy have Rep as 713 ??

Comment: @ManseUK it is true w3school is not the most accurate ressource for js and css , but frankly , moz docs are simply just horrible to read , unfriendly , etc ... w3school is simple but very clear and you can quickly get infos about apis ,etc ... accurate , no  , but easier to read than moz website definetly. I wish i was not the case ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript functions to do this functionality...

And with this, you have to use image functions of PHP...